# How to find another linearly independent solution for the DE System of repeated eigenvalues?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, systems-of-equations

Given the differential equations system I need to find a general solution considering $t\gt0$ $$t\vec x '=\begin{pmatrix}
    3 & -4  \\
    1 & -1   \\
    \end{pmatrix} \vec x$$

A solution has the form
$\vec x=\vec u t^r$ so that $(A-rI)\vec u=0$

The matrix has a repeated eigen value $\lambda=1$ so one solution is
$$\vec x =\begin{pmatrix}
    2   \\
    1   \\
    \end{pmatrix} t$$

But now in the problem of finding another solution wich is not a multiple of the one I have found I do not know how to proceed, wich form shall the solution have as I suppose from other problems it should be something like
$$\vec x=\begin{pmatrix}
    2   \\
    1   \\
    \end{pmatrix} tg(t)+  \begin{pmatrix}
    1   \\
    0   \\
    \end{pmatrix} t$$

Where $(A-I)\begin{pmatrix}
    1   \\
    0   \\
    \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}
    2   \\
    1   \\
    \end{pmatrix} $

So how can I find another solution for the system?

Comment: Have you learned about finding a Generalized Eigenvector? See: https://www.math.fsu.edu/~bellenot/class/s06/la2/geneigen.pdf

Comment: If the matrix is not a multiple of the identity, you can decompose it into the sum of a diagonal matrix and a nilpotent matrix.

Comment: Isnt there another way? Im hinted that $g(t)=lnt$ but dont know why